# Error con el evento hover de jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Sres llevo días tratando de solucionar un error que tengo un una pagina web que estoy diseñando, resulta que tengo una imagen con un mapa, sobre esta imagen voy a situar varias ubicaciones en las cuales al pasar el mouse sobre ellas debe desplegar el nombre y logo de la institución. las ubicaciones las tengo con varios li dentro de un ul

```js
$('.afect').hover(function(){
    $('.animation').css({
      "opacity": "1",
      "transform": "scale(1)"
    });
    },function(){
          $('.animation').css({
            "opacity": "0",
            "transform": "scale(0.3)"
          })
      });

$('.afect1').hover(function(){
    $('.animation1').css({
         "opacity": "1",
         "transform": "scale(1)"
});
     },function(){
            $('.animation1').css({
                "opacity": "0",
                "transform": "scale(0.3)"
        })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <!-- Malvern -->
    <li class="malvern">
      <i class="icon-conos_dir afect" ></i> 
      <div class="cont-logo animation" >
        <div>
          <img src="img/agustporelmundo/malvern.png" alt="">
        </div>

      </div>
      <span class="animation"><img src="img/agustporelmundo/flag-us.png" alt="">Malvern preparatory school</span>
    </li>

    <!-- Europa -->
    <li class="europa">
      <i class="icon-conos_dir afect1"></i>
      <div class="cont-logo animation1">
        <div>
          <img src="img/agustporelmundo/malvern.png" alt="">
        </div>
      </div>
      <span class="animation1" ><img src="img/agustporelmundo/flag-us.png" alt="">Europa</span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

El problema radica es que al posarme sobre las ubicaciones solo me funciona es el ultimo li que ubique, siempre los anteriores quedan inhabilitado, es decir al colocar el mouse sobre ellos no se despliega el nombre y logo

Comment: No se visualizan tus imágenes. Crees que las puedas subir a un online hosting, como este **[imgur](https://imgur.com/)**, y después actualizar tu código con las nuevas urls?